# access denied randomly for all users

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh

It will randomly happen that access is denied for all users including 'root'. I am sure I input the right password and sometimes it will work.
[access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o40Sk.png)[other users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNyrc.png)

and here's the system log in /var/log/auth.log
[auth.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkZiC.jpg)

can anybody tell me what's the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try another keyboard? Maybe a key is stuck, that gives "double strokes" - I'm experiencing this myself. The log does not reveal anything unusual.

Comment: All members of the our server have come into this trouble before , so I think the problem is not on the keyboard. Thank you for your reply though.